# DTD exactly 2 elements

Tags: xml, dtd

i found that in previous exam  , he is asking us to write DTD :

"There is exactly one velocity element inside the sensor-system element, followed by exactly two temperature elements with a mandatory location attribute"

so it is

```
<!ELEMENT sensor-system(velcoity,temperature+)>
```

how come he wants exactly so temperatures ? is that even possible ?
can  I write thhat or it is not correct

```
<!ELEMENT sensor-system(velcoity,temperature,temperature)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, also, do not forget to declare your temperature element like so:

`<!ELEMENT temperature (location)>`

Comment: u mean        <!ATTLIST temperature location #REQUIRED > ?